# No se cargan los estilos de Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap, yarn

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en react e importé *bootstrap* por medio de `yarn add boostrap` pero no me funciona. La única manera en la que lo puedo importar sin que genere error es `import 'boostrap/package.json';`.

Sin embargo trato de usarlo en un componente y no funciona. Cuando digo que no funciona es que parece que no lo estuviera utilizando, parece *html* simple y carga los diseños.

**Archivo index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'boostrap/package.json';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Componente Menu.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
const Menu = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  bg-dark">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="nav-item'">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to='/'>Inicio</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                <Link  className="nav-link" to='/login'>Login</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                <Link  className="nav-link" to='/admin'>Admin</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Menu
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Inicio from './components/Inicio';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Admin from './components/Admin';
import Menu from './components/Menu';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Router>
      <Menu></Menu>
      <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<Inicio/>}></Route>
      <Route path='/admin' element={<Admin/>}></Route>
      <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}></Route>
      </Routes>

      </Router>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Pista: `booTstrap`, no `boostrap`.

Comment: @padaleiana Muchas gracias!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación de la [API](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#css), deberías importarlo así:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Lo que estás importando actualmente es un archivo JSON, no la librería.

Saludos.